# Checking for events, logging times, and interacting with PowerPoint from a Python program

Tags: python, powerpoint

Is there a way to have a Python program to "listen" for an event?

I'd like to create a small program that 'looks for/waits' for Presentation Mode in PowerPoint to be activated. Once it recognizes that it has started, I want to log the times that the user spends on each slide.

What would be the best way to go about this? Are there any good modules to use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll have to use a [macro](http://notes.indezine.com/2007/11/use-macros-and-scripts-in-powerpoint.html) to execute a specific script.

I don't know of any way for a Python program to listen for a PowerPoint event.